# cordova plugin add via git fails, but only from a TeamCity build agent process

Tags: node.js, git, cordova, teamcity

Our cordova builds in TeamCity have started failing while adding plugins. The plugins that are fetched via npm work fine. There are a few which we still install via git for various reasons (haven't been added to the registry, internal/private, etc.)

The error we get is the infamous

> fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'

Questions about that error have been asked before, but the solutions to those questions have not helped, as this problem only exists in the context of a TeamCity build agent process spawning a cordova plugin add which in turn spawns the git clone (via node's child_process.spawn).

Some things we know so far

1. On the same build agent machine, as the build agent service account,
   we can add this plugin at a command prompt with no issues.
2. On the same build agent, same service account, we can git clone the associated repo at the command prompt with no issue.
3. We altered the cordova source to log out the cmd, args,
   and spawnOptions passed to child_process.spawn in superspawn.js. We watch
   that fail from the TeamCity build agent process, but can send the
   same args to child_process.spawn in our own node script and it clones fine. For what it's worth, here is the child_process.spawn line created from the args in the build log: `child_process.spawn('C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\bin\\git.exe ', ['clone','--depth=1', 'https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-backgroundaudio','C:\\TeamCity\\buildAgent\\temp\\buildTmp\\git\\1448324988055' ], {});`
4. We've confirmed that the build agent process is running the same
   version of node, npm, and git as we have interactively at the
   command prompt.
5. We don't see any environment variables in the build agent process
   that seem relevant or different from what we have at an interactive
   command prompt.
6. We've tried reinstalling git, node, and the build agent itself.

Nothing has seemed to help. I'm hoping that someone else has seen this before and can point us toward what we're missing. If not, I'll answer my own question once we get this sorted out.

Comment: I'm fine having this moved to Super User or Server Fault. My reasoning for asking here is that build pipelines and associated tools are specifically programming related. This is not general hardware/software (e.g., "My audio doesn't work after my computer sleeps!" or "Laptop won't connect to wireless!"), nor is it server / infrastructure related ("Can't connect to network" or "Failed to join AD") .